# How to install the Windows 7 Canon CR2 (Raw) driver on a netbook or other low resolution device

Tags: drivers, resolution, camera-raw

When you attempt to install the [Cannon Raw Driver](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/windows_vista/cameras/eos_slr_camera_systems/canon_raw_codec_software#DriversAndSoftware) on a machine with less than 1024x768 resolution you get the following error message

[image: This software does not support screen resolutions lower than 1024x768. Please change your screen resolution to 1024x768 or higher.]

I have a [Dell Inspiron Mini 1012](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-mini1012/fs?cs=19) with a maximum resolution of 1024x600. It is running windows 7. As per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/50501/change-screen-resolution-to-exceed-the-maximum-on-windows-7), there is no built in tool for Windows for setting a higher virtual resolution than your physical resolution. My video driver does not include one either.

So is their an alternative installer for this driver without the resolution requirement, or is there a way to install this driver without attaching an external monitor?

**Note:** If you do want to go the external monitor route, which I just did, it is necessary to make the external minitor the "main" monitor.

Comment: If you're on Windows 7 at-least-Professional you could RDP to it and pick a resolution for your remote desktop >= 1024 x 768

Answer (score 2):

If your edition of Windows 7 is at least Windows 7 Professional, you should be able to use Remote Desktop to connect to your laptop remotely. When connecting, choose a resolution of at least 1024 x 768 for your remote desktop.

Typing your problem into Google yielded [this answer and a link](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showpost.php?p=7248614&postcount=12) which suggests that if your laptop has an Intel GMA video adapter (and another Google search suggests it does), you can use [AsTray Plus](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/astrayplus) to increase the resolution of your screen.

> AsTray Plus is a freeware, which was developed by BASSAM.
>
> The basic function for this utility is to emulate and switch customized resolutions for Eeepc.
>
> It was programmed for non-platform-limited, which means AsTray Plus should work for all computers which have an intel GMA device installed.