# How to resize a window so it is larger than the physical screen?

Tags: windows-xp

I want to resize a window so it is larger than the physical screen, possibly using free software. I intend to use a GNU software, gvwm, to navigate the different parts of the big window.

Description of [gvwm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvwm/):

> gvwm provides grid of virtual desktops for Windows, allowing the user's workspace to be larger than the screen area.The practical upshot is that you can have several "desktops", allowing you to sort your windows and have a less cluttered workspace.

The windows I`d like to enlarge could be a browser window, office document, jpg viewer, etc.

I have searched for a registry tweak, and searched for a virtual desktop manager, but found nothing yet.

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicates [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123410/), for what it's worth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change screen resolution to exceed the maximum on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/50501/change-screen-resolution-to-exceed-the-maximum-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

I found a download of ScreenSpace with the [Waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112105944/http://www.dandeware.com/products/) and it worked for me on Windows 10 and Minecraft Java.