# Intel HD Graphics 3000: Screen resolution greater than panel's?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, intel-graphics, optimus

From time to time, I need to create screenshots at a resolution higher than the display of my laptop. It has two graphics cards, an Intel HD Graphics 3000, and an NVIDIA NVS 4200M. In the BIOS I can switch the system to *discrete graphics*. Then, in the NVIDIA settings, I can select a resolution higher than what my screen supports. However, that's cumbersome as it requires a reboot: Normally I run the system with both graphics cards enabled (Optimus), which means that the Windows 7 X64 desktop environment is controlled by the Intel graphics adapter.

*Can I set a custom resolution, exceeding my screen's resolution, for an Intel HD Graphics 3000? If so, how?*

Sometimes such a resolution is called a *virtual screen resolution.*

**Update:** Yes, I am aware of the question [Change screen resolution to exceed the maximum on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/50501/change-screen-resolution-to-exceed-the-maximum-on-windows-7). However, it is *not* a duplicate as I am interested in a solution that the Intel HD Graphics 3000 GPU handles in hardware. Also, I am looking for a temporary solution that I can turn on for some minutes once in a while. I prefer not to have another service running in the background. Furthermore, I am *not* interested in *virtual desktops*, which allow moving windows to virtual screens.

**Workarounds I tried to no avail:** (actually unrelated to this question as those are non-hardware
solutions)

- [GiMeSpace](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter): I am not able to change the vertical dimensions of the Chrome 40 window to 
  greater than those of the screen. Also, there are undesired side effects such as the [DU Meter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter)
  mini window scrolling out of sight when activating GiMeSpace.
- [Infinite Screen](http://ynea.futureware.at/cgi-bin/infinite_screen.pl): When I resized Chrome 40 to 2000px height, which is larger than the height
  of my screen, it started misbehaving. Taking screenshots with Awesome Screenshot didn't work
  anymore, and content of tabs disappeared, even after resizing the window back to normal.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Can you explain how this is a duplicate? I am looking for an in-hardware solution for the Intel HD Graphics 3000 GPU.

Comment: It's still the same question IMO, just because you state which graphics card you are using doesn't make it a different question. But hey, others can vote to reopen if they feel it worth having it's own question. A question that will be VERY narrow in scope, since you're saying to want to do it in a specific way for a specific version of a specific card. Perhaps you could expand on why the existing answers on the existing question don't suit your needs... What did you try already?

Comment: IMO you should be just putting a Bounty on the existing question, asking for newer/different answers, perhaps specific to your card (you can comment as to why you're placing a bounty).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I tried the software-only solutions, but they don't work. That's why I'm looking for a hardware/driver solution such as available for Nvidia GPUs. If someone presents a solution that works for other Intel GPUs as well, then I'm happy to update my question to give it a broader appeal. Just as of now, it's not even possible to post an answer, as the question is closed.