# Is there a way to increase monitor resolution by some software?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, memory, resolution

I want to control many windows without tab thing, just use keys on Numpad to change position and size of controlled area by "+" and "-".
For example, there are 4 windows 2 with Virtualbox, and two with a browser, when I'll press "-" I want to see a small area, only Virtual box, and when I press num 6, the area should move and show part of next window. For "+" it's should increase the size of controlled area and show more and more windows.

Comment: Used this one https://www.displayfusion.com/ a while ago, as far as I remember, that option is available here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *commercial* solution which I found here https://superuser.com/a/173549/761111.  [Free version](http://download.cnet.com/GiMeSpace-Free-Edition/3000-2346_4-75042748.html?part=dl-&subj=dl&tag=button) from sites google gimespace (it redirects you to another site *without* free link available)   **but** can move **only horizontally** and **has ads** & without key features I mentioned, also **top** answer contain suspectable software with 7 viruses(can't comment cause have < 50 reputations points) check out [here](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/b97261daa1d2c14a1e211feaae38f6a311471e8e949cab35eefa8f82f9ec2219/detection).

Comment: Important : [free version](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/fc67fb940ae22556d0da60a358b4f267e50dfc0ba6e349ed7aeff74debf5c88f/detection) has 2 viruses, but a fast google search tells that it's harmless.

Comment: That page you linked to indicated that seven virus scanners detected a virus, not that there are seven viruses in the file. Note also that that link had three "safe" votes by "the community" and the second link only has one. Also note that several of the flags seem to be heuristic-based rather than a fingerprint. P.S. I have no idea what has transpired in this question, I'm only pointing out that your links don't provide strong evidence of viruses in either case.

Comment: Possibly , but it's not a page , it's file , [check it out](http://imgur.com/a/n3RCK)

Comment: By page, I mean the virustotal URL.

Comment: but you said that I linked virus total of the site link , not file. Again, there is no other files, its standalone .exe application, did you see [> it <](http://imgur.com/a/n3RCK) I dropped a file , not a link.

Comment: I said you posted a link to a page (detailing information on a file).

Comment: @lungj yep, but check out [this page](http://alternativeto.net/software/gimespace-desktop-extender/) it's got 12 points and  2 comments, where your p̶r̶o̶m̶o̶t̶i̶o̶n̶a̶l̶  [software](http://alternativeto.net/software/infinite-screen/) has only 3 ,  obviously due to viruses